# Viewing data of selected row from <p:dataTable> through <p:dialog>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having this problem displaying the data of the selected row from the DataTable using Dialog.

[image]
Each row that im selecting displays the data of the first top row(parent row) in the Dialog

[image]

Deleting other rows work fine. i've been working days for this but still cant solve this one.

Here is my code in DataTable

```
<h:form id="tableForm">

        <!-- Account Data Table --> 


        <p:dataTable id="table" var="account" value="#{accountController.accounts}" widgetVar="accountTable" rowKey="#{account.id}" paginator="true" rows="15"
                     paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" selection="#{accountController.account}"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom" lazy="true">  


            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:18px" />

            <p:column headerText="Lastname" sortBy="#{account.marketingPerson.lastName}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{account.marketingPerson.lastName}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Firstname" sortBy="#{account.marketingPerson.firstName}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{account.marketingPerson.firstName}" />  
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Middlename" sortBy="#{account.marketingPerson.middleName}">  
                <h:outputText value="#{account.marketingPerson.middleName}" />  
            </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Position">  
                <h:outputText value="#{account.marketingPerson.position}" />  
            </p:column>   

            <f:facet name="footer">

                <!-- View Button -->
                <p:commandButton value="View" oncomplete="view.show()" icon="view-icon" >

                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{accountController.account}" value="#{account}"/>

                </p:commandButton>

                <!-- Edit Button -->
                <p:commandButton  value="Edit" onclick="view.show()" icon="edit-icon">

                </p:commandButton>

                <!-- Delete Button -->
                <p:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="cd.show()" icon="delete-icon" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{accountController.account}" value="#{account}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>     

        </p:dataTable> 

        <!-- Confirmation -->
        <p:confirmDialog 
            header="Delete Action Confirmation" severity="alert"
            widgetVar="cd">

            <f:facet name="message">
                <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:commandButton value="Yes" actionListener="#{accountController.delete}" update="table"
                             oncomplete="cd.hide()">
                <f:ajax render="table" />
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="cd.hide()" type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
```

View Account Dialog

```
<p:dialog header="View Account" widgetVar="view" resizable="false" id="viewDlg" draggable="false" >         
        <h:form id="viewForm">
            <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" style="margin:0 auto;">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p> <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/icons-button/search_business_user.png" />
                        #{account.marketingPerson.lastName}, #{account.marketingPerson.firstName} #{account.marketingPerson.middleName}
                    </p>
                </f:facet>

                <p:outputLabel value="ID Number:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{account.marketingPerson.idNumber}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Birth Date:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{account.marketingPerson.birthDate}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Telephone Number:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{account.marketingPerson.telNumber}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Mobile Number:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{account.marketingPerson.mobileNumber}" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Email Address:" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{account.marketingPerson.emailAddress}" />

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Edit" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Hello zaidoRed: You have not updated your view dialog from `<p:commandButton value="View" onclick="view.show()" icon="view-icon">`. You can try updating view dialog on `View` button click.

Comment: im getting identifying error with this. tried <p:commandButton value="View" onclick="view.show()" icon="view-icon update="viewDlg">

Comment: Can you remove your `<h:form id="viewForm">` and place your `view dialog` in your `<h:form id="tableForm">` ? If you have no limitations to do so. If you can so then add attribute `update=":tableForm:display"`

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work. also tried adding <f:ajax render=":tableForm:display"/> yet still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one using Faces Converter

Answer (score 1):

Use `p:ajax` on your DataTable to update the value on ManagedBean every time you select the data from Table.
And use `update` attribute the to Re render `p:panelGrid` in `p:dialog` with new selected value.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":viewForm:display" />
```

Comment: Cannot find component with identifier ":viewForm:display" referenced from "form:tableForm:table". Tried inserting <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":viewForm:display" />  to the DataTable

Comment: Where is your form with id="viewform" ? if you're using firefox get the id of the p:panelGrid from Inspect element option by right clicking on the View Account dialog and put that id in <p:ajax update="id of panelgrid">.

Comment: i have two forms, the form(id=tableForm) and form(id=viewForm) inside the <p:dialog>. im using chrome.

Comment: In chrome also Inspect element is,there just right click on the dialog. see this https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Comment: still not working. inserting <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="form:viewForm:display"/> inside the dataTable, disabled the selection function and displaying the dialog. Idk but i guess updating is not the solution. im wondering why is it that the dataTable returns its parent row as the default value. i cant even delete the parent row

Comment: Is #{account.id}  same for all entries in datatable? RowKey must be unique.

Comment: i believe each rowKeys are unique. removing the rowKey=#{account.id} causes this error "DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled."